# I'm getting segmentation fault when I call a comparison function

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I'm having segmentation fault when I call `comparaTo`. I've tried some ways to pass the arguments, and I think the error is it.

```
typedef struct No{
    struct Object * valor;
    /** ramo de nós esquerda */
    struct No * esq;
    /** ramo de nós centro */
    struct No * cnt;
    /** ramo de nós direita */
    struct No * dir;
}No;`

  typedef struct Object {
    char nome[MAX_NOME];
    int idade;
    float altura;
 }Object;   

int comparaTo(struct Object * a, struct Object * b){
    int resto = (a->idade + b->idade)%3;
    return resto;
}

void insere(struct No ** T, struct No * x){
    int resto = comparaTo((**T).valor, (*x).valor);
        if(resto == 0){
            (*T)->esq = x;
    }
    else if(resto == 1){
        (*T)->cnt = x;
    }
    else{
        (*T)->dir = x;
    }
}
```

Comment: please add your structs also, `No` and `Object`.

Comment: `int resto = comparaTo((**T).valor, (*x).valor);`

Comment: What do you expect `(a->idade, b->idade)%3` to do?

Comment: `int resto = (a->idade, b->idade)%3;` This is most certainly wrong. `(a->idade, b->idade)` is equivalent to `b->idade`.

Comment: One of the following pointers is invalid: `T`, `(*T)`, `(*T)->valor`, `x`, `x->valor`

Comment: Are you trying to compare addresses to see if they are the same object?

Comment: Please peovide a complete program that shows the problem, or use a debugger.